# how to populate the FB privacy URL programmatically

Tags: facebook, privacy

http://screencast.com/t/COmDrTap

Hi, I have a bunch of apps that I would programmatically like to update the privacy polity URL and the ToS URL.

When I went into the graph explorer for the graffiti app (or on one of mine), the privacy URL as dimmed out (also the app name when I tried that).

Does this mean it cannot be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it as all other parameters, using https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/ as endpoint and **privacy_policy_url** as parameter name.

Comment: it will work but you will need to pass an auth token.

https://graph.facebook.com/thefbappidnumber?fields=privacy_policy_url&access_token=awesomeauthtoken